# Jenkins global functions

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Suppose I have a powershell function:

```
function checkFile 
{
    if (Test-Path $args[0]) { 
        if((Get-Item $args[0]).length -gt 0kb){
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}
```

Is it possible to make this function accessible to all projects in jenkins so that I don't have to define `checkFile` in every powershell script?

I know how to define global variables in jenkins. But currently it seems not possible to define global functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [Managed Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin)!